# Why is $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z/12\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z/40\Bbb Z$ not isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/8\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z/10\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z/24\Bbb Z$?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism

Why is $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z/12\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z/40\Bbb Z$ not isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/8\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z/10\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z/24\Bbb Z$?

I was thinking to show that they have distinct number of subgroups of the same order, or maybe they have different number of elements of a given order. Since I know they are abelian, have the same order, they are not cyclic, they have subgroups and elements of order for every divisor of 1920, so it is the only idea I have left. Or maybe using the Fundamental Theorem for Finite Abelian Groups?

But, the problem is I don't know how to recognize the number of subgroups or elements of a given order, of course, efficiently. Because I could waste my day looking for all the subgroups and elements of a given order but that is not the idea.

I would be thankful if someone can guide me in the right way.

Comment: Use `$\times$` for $\times$.

Comment: Look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2614714/showing-that-2-of-the-following-groups-are-not-isomorphic) (instead of "wasting your day looking for all the subgroups").

Comment: These groups do not have elements of every order that divides 1920. If they did, then they would both have an element of order 1920, and they would both be the group $Z/1920\Bbb{Z}$ Can you think of an integer $n$ for which only one of these groups has an element of order $n$?

Comment: The second group has an element of order $2$ and no square root.

Answer (score 5):

One simple way to see this is that the second group has an element $(0,5,0)$ of order $2$ and no element $g$ such that $g+g=(0,5,0).$

There is no element like this in the first group.

If $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb Z_4\times\mathbb Z_{12}\times\mathbb Z_{40}$ is of order $2,$ then $2x$ is divisible by $4,$ $2y$ has to be divisible by $12$ and $2z$ has to be divisible by $40.$ But that means $x,y,z$ have to be even, and there is an element $g$ such that $g+g=(x,y,z).$

---

I found this element by factorizing the groups, and found the second group had a factor $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z,$ and $(0,5,0)$ corresponds to the $1$ in $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z.$

In general, a finite abelian group has an element like this if and only if the fundamental theorem factorization has a factor of $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z.$

More generally, if $A$ is a finite abelian group with a factor $\mathbb Z/p^k\mathbb Z,$ then $A$ has an element $a$ of order $p^k$ such that $pb=a$ has no solution $b.$

This can often be used to find examples in one group but not another, but it doesn't work all the time, for example, comparing:$$\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z\times\left(\mathbb Z/p^2\mathbb Z\right)^2\\
\left(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z\right)^3\times\mathbb Z/p^2\mathbb Z.$$

Now the difference between these groups is in the *number* of elements of order $p$ which do not have $p$th roots.

Answer (score 2):

We have that the first group is isomorphic to

$$\Bbb Z_4\times(\Bbb Z_3\times \Bbb Z_4)\times (\Bbb Z_5\times \Bbb Z_8),$$

while the second group is isomorphic to

$$\Bbb Z_8\times(\Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_5)\times (\Bbb Z_3\times\Bbb Z_8).$$

This uses the following lemma:

> **Lemma:** For any $a,b\in\Bbb N$, we have
> $$\gcd(a,b)=1\iff\Bbb Z_{ab}\cong \Bbb Z_a\times \Bbb Z_b.$$

*For a proof, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/5969/104041).*

Therefore, by the Fundamental Theorem of Finite Abelian Groups, they are not isomorphic.

Comment: An easy way to see this also is that you can rearrange the order of the cross products and stay isomorphic,  so it comes down to the fact that $\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_8 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$